# ES6 style child process in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm a backyard developer, using Node.js for a number of projects. I'm also attempting to use ES6 classes where possible, as I prefer the way structure is imposed. However, I'm having problems getting child processes to function with ES6 classes.

For testing, test1.js, a traditional module:

```
var cp = require( 'child_process' );
var kid = cp.fork( 'test2.js' );
kid.send( {msg: "Hey there kid"} );
setTimeout( () => { process.exit(0) }, 2000 );
```

And test2.js

```
console.log( "Regular child is alive now" );
function yay( message ) { console.log( "Regular kid got", message ); }
process.on( 'message', (m) => { yay(m) } );
```

The same in ES6, test1.mjs:

```
import cp from 'child_process';
const kid = cp.fork( 'test2.mjs' );
kid.send( { msg: "Hey there kid" } );
setTimeout( () => { process.exit(0) }, 2000 );
```

And test2.mjs

```
class Test2 {
  constructor() {
    console.log( "Experimental child is alive now" );
  }
  yay(message) {
    console.log( "Experimental kid got", message );
  }
}
const test2 = new Test2();
process.on( 'message', (m) => { test2.yay(m) } );
```

Executing these, only the traditional child receives the message. The experimental one logs it's instantiation, but no message received.

What am I doing wrong? Or are ES6 modules well out of scope for Node.js (using --experimental-modules flag)?

EDIT:

I've asked this question on n Node.js help git tracker too, and had the issue pointed out. The send() was occurring before the IPC connection was established. Putting the kid.send() into a setTimeout demonstrated this. As it was pointed out to me, no message exchange should be attempted without a confirmed connection.

Comment: What version of node are you on? Its working fine for me on v8.10.0

Comment: Love the `backyard developer` part...

Comment: Perhaps use Babel transpilation if your Node version doesn't support ES6?

Comment: @Nitin, do you get the 'experimental kid got...' message? I'm running 8 something recent, just away from the machine for a while.

Comment: @Nitin, confirming, I'm running 8.11.2. I get the "Experimental child is alive now" message, but not the 'Experimental kid got...' one.

Answer (score 2):

Install babel

```
npm install babel-register babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Create entry point `index.js` file that calls `test1.js`

```
require('babel-register')({ presets: [ 'es2015' ] });

require('./test1.js');
```

Now try `node index.js`

```
➜  node index.js 
Experimental child is alive now
Experimental kid got { msg: 'Hey there kid' }
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I was really hoping to have this working without transpiling from babel. I'm digging deeper into the issue. It appears to be related to IPC with ES6. Still, this may be an option.

Comment: please note the edit to the post. The problem in my test case has been identified.

Comment: Thanks for this! Was going around in circles for ages

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'createRequire', it's very simple (Tested with NodeJs 14.15.5) :

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const shellExec = require('child_process');
```

and in your code :

```
shellExec.exec(command,callback);
```

You can also use other methods from shellExec like
ChilldProcess , execFile, execFileSync, Fork, spawn, spawnSync

I often use this technic for "old modules" not supporting "import", like MongoDb.